# Is it possible to search by geo-shape type in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have the following index mapping:

```
PUT testing/_mapping
{
  "properties": {
    "location": {
      "type": "geo_shape"
    }
  }
}
```

I index two documents:

```
PUT testing/_doc/1
{
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [13.400544, 52.530286]
  }
}
PUT testing/_doc/2
{
  "location": {
    "type" : "linestring",
    "coordinates" : [[-77.03653, 38.897676], [-77.009051, 38.889939]]
  }
}
```

Now I would like to find documents by their geo-shape type, e.g. only document where `type=point` (document 1). Is it possible in Elasticsearch? I have tried following search but it always return 0 results.

```
GET testing/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "location.type": {
              "value": "point"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I'm using Elasticsearch 7.2.1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot search by the `location.type` field, it's not searchable.

What I suggest is that you also index the type of your shape in another field, like this:

```
PUT testing/_doc/1
{
  "location": {
    "type": "point",
    "coordinates": [13.400544, 52.530286]
  },
  "type": "point"
}
PUT testing/_doc/2
{
  "location": {
    "type" : "linestring",
    "coordinates" : [[-77.03653, 38.897676], [-77.009051, 38.889939]]
  },
  "type": "linestring"
}
```

And then you can search like this:

```
GET testing/_search
{
  "query":{
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "term": {
            "type.keyword": "point"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```